# Selecting the same date for every year SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to create a proc to select the same date every 3 years.

Example: DOB = '2020-01-01'

I need my proc to insert a row into a table every 3 years on that specific date. So on 2023-01-01 I need the proc to insert a row into a table and then on 2026-01-01 and so on and so on.

Comment: Support `DOB` were `2020-02-29` instead - what future dates should be populated? Also, consider whether you need to *store* this data at all, since it seems like it can be trivially re-derived from `DOB` as required.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: If you want something to occur based on the passage of time, you need to schedule that. Most editions of sql server support the sql server agent where you can schedule tasks. For the express version, you can use the OS task scheduler or any similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateadd()`:

```
select dateadd(year, n.n, @dob)
from (values (3), (6), (9)) n(n);
```

Just put `insert` before this if you want to insert the results into a table.